# Doubt about transpose operation in SVD matrix tutorial

Tags: matrix

I am trying to get a grasp of the Singular value Decomposition of a matrix following [this tutorial](https://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm).

I am confused however by the way they transpose the matrix A.
From what I understood from the transposition operation,
`|A |B |`           -----------------------------     `|A |C |0 |0 |`
`|C |D |`     ---  should transpose to ---     `|B |D |0 |0 |`
`|0 |0 |`
`|0 |0 |`

Or did I misunderstand the transpose process?

Comment: Are you asking what a matrix transpose is? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; that's how transposes work.

I think you're asking because the page shows the computation of $A A^T = W$, but the transpose $A^T$ is incorrect. Their given value of $W$ is correct according to the conventional definition of transpose (which you gave), so it seems that it's only $A^T$ that's incorrectly written.

---

Given that
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
the transpose should be
\begin{equation}
A^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 3 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and not
\begin{equation}
A^T \color{red}{\neq} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & \color{red}{4} & 0 & 0 \\ \color{red}{1} & 3 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
which your linked tutorial gave.

---

It might be nice to email the owner of the page to clue them in. :)

Comment: Thats what I thought but as I did not really get the SVD, I was wondering if i misundertood everything, thanks.
that means the whole calculations are false right?

Comment: They only wrote $A^T$ down wrong; they didn't use it incorrectly in their calculations. $W$ is correct, and I assume everything following it is too, but I'm not going to check the entire page.

Comment: alright if W is correct then it should be fine, thanks